# terminal cat command removes character and tab

Tags: linux, csv, centos7, cat

I'm on a mac and I ssh into a linux box to copy a tsv file. The tsv file has a header row of the following:

> Recipient Id  Recipient Type  Mailing Id  Report Id   Campaign Id Email   Event Type  Event Timestamp Body Type   Content Id  Click Name  URL Conversion Action   Conversion Detail   Conversion Amount   Suppression Reason  Mailing Name

When I run the cat command for the file it shows the header row as

> Recipient Id  Recipient Type  Mailing Id  Report Id   Campaign Id Email   Event Type  Event Timestamp Body Type   Content Id  Click Name  URL Conversion Action   Conversion Detail   Conversion AmounSuppression Reason  Mailing Name

Notice that it says "Conversion AmounSuppression Reason". It does this for multiple files (every file I've checked does it) and it does it every time. It only seems to happen on the header row also. When I open the file with vi it shows correctly.

Has anyone ever seen this happen before? Is this some weird bug in cat? I can't replicate on my mac, this only happens on the linux machine.

The linux box is running
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

and cat --version
cat (GNU coreutils) 8.22

Comment: Please show the output of `od -c -tx1 your_file`, or if the file is big, show `od -c -tx1 your_file | head -20`. Please format commands and output in your question as code by selecting the code text and using the `{}` tool of the editor field.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and UNIX & Linux StackExchange cover general questions.